# Awarded the Populist badge multiple times for a single answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, populist-badge

Looks like the answer used to fulfill the requirements for the badge, then for some time didn't and now did again, and thus triggered multiple awards of the badge for a single answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/badges/62/populist?userid=57986

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah ... looks like something odd is going on ... this happened to 362 people.

I will revoke all these badges regularly in the weekly job.

This appears to be an old issue with our scheduler we fixed since.